# How to hide a control and prevent control from loading data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls

I have a page that have the following code for a custom control:

```
<SiteControls:Announcements runat="server" id="UserAnnouncements" />
```

Let's also say I have a GridView control, just so I can cover multiple scenarios. I need to check if the user has permission to view this control by checking the Boolean:

```
PermissionsManagement.DoesUserHavePermission(userId, permissionId)
```

Which is defined as:

```
public static class PermissionsManagement
{
    public static bool DoesUserHavePermission(int userAccountId, int permissionId)
    {
        // Code Goes Here
    }
}
```

If the user doesn't have permission, DoesUserHavePermission will return false. I have the ASP.NET WebForms page laid out as if the user has full control (meaning I have all the controls on the page and want to remove them if they don't have permission vs adding every single control to the page).

I can set the control's visibility to false on Page_Load function if the user doesn't have permission, but that doesn't stop my control from loading or in the case of a GridView from loading its data. How do I stop a control (User control or standard control) from loading any data if the user doesn't have permission to use (view) the control? I have tried the following inline code which doesn't work:

```
<% if(PermissionsManagement.DoesUserHavePermission(1, 1))
   { %>
        <SiteControls:Announcements runat="server" id="UserAnnouncements" />
<% } %>
```

But that doesn't work as the control Page_Load still fires for the control and I assume any other control will load data if it is data-bound or acts similar to my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing much of your code, it is a little difficult to figure out the exact answer. However, as much as I understood your question, here's my answer.

Loading data for `Announcements` or `GridView` should still be in your control. I would expose a method in Announcements control that actually loads data for it. For the GridView you should simply defer the binding of `DataSource` until the permission check is performed. Of course these things need to be done in addition to hiding (setting visibility) of these controls.

See the code below, not complete, but enough to express an idea:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Check permissions here
        if (allowed) 
        {
            // For custom/user control
            UserAnnouncements.GetAnnouncements();
            // For grid view
            GridView1.DataSource = GetGridviewData(); // GetGridviewData would return DataSet or anything valid.
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            // Hide the controls
        }
    }
}
```